# Expanding a brace expansion string held in a variable for use in a for loop?

Tags: bash, string, brace-expansion

I've got the following script:

```
FOOS=foo{1..5}
for i in `echo $FOOS` do
echo bar
done
```

Now I (think I) get the idea that the brace expansion only works with literals - hence the echo - but all this seems to do is print just one `bar` to the console. Why (is string/brace expansion not working)?

What I'd expect to happen is:

1. Assign the string (`foo{1..5}`) representing an expansion to variable `FOOS`
2. substitute `$FOOS`, so I've basically got
       `for i in 'echo foo{1..5}' do` (looks like I can't escape back-ticks here)
3. execute echo, so I now have `for i in foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5 do`
4. execute for, printing `bar` five times to the console output
5. Not get just one `bar` printed on screen as the only output :-)

Comment: Your first line doesn't work.  `$ FOOS = foo{1..5}
FOOS: command not found`.  Please fix and provide the script exactly as is.

Comment: paste your script onto shellcheck.net and click the arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
FOO=$(echo foo{1..5})
```

but better is to use an array

```
FOO=(foo{1..5})
```

2.

```
echo ${FOO[*]}
```

4.

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    echo bar
done
```

or

```
for i in $(seq 5)
do
    echo bar
done
```

Comment: Just use FOO=( {1..5} )。

Comment: What am I doing wrong? `v=$( echo {1,20{0..3}} ); echo $v` yields `1 200 201 202 203` yet `v=( {1,20{0..3}} ); echo $v` yields only `1`. Answer: Use `echo ${v[*]}`!